# Compile fail. SDL problem

Tags: compiling, make, sdl

When I try to compile this program using make command, it fails. I think I have all the neccessary libraries for this. Here is the screen shot of the trerminal with the compile fail.

[image]

And here is a part of the readme file:

```
        <=============SETTUP=============>

    To install the game, you will need the GNU GCC (G++) compiler as 
well as the SDL library v1.2 or greater and SDL_image extension 
library (for quicker and more versatile image loading) and SDL_ttf (for using true type fonts).

    After unpacking the archive, open up a terminal window,
browse to the folder where you unpacked and type in "make". The source
files have now been compiled, and you can now run the program by typing
./Invaders.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command to install all the requirements mentioned in your post. And then do `./make`

`sudo apt-get install libtiff4 libtiff4-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev`

Comment: :( Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libsdl1.2-dev is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. Thismay mean that you have
requestedanimpossiblesituationorifyouareusingthe unstabledistributionthatsomerequired packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmetdependencies:
  libsdl-image1.2-dev: Depends: libtiff4-dev but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Updated answer with tiff library. Please try now.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libsdl1.2-dev is already the newest version.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libtiff4-dev: Depends: libtiff4 (= 3.9.2-2) but 3.9.2-2ubuntu0.7 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: I have this Ubuntu: ubuntu-desktop-10.04.4-tmd018-dvd.iso in VMware if that makes any difference. And here is the game http://www.acs.uns.ac.rs/sr/filebrowser/download/1430161

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
Execute these commands  one by one and then execute the command in the answer section.

Comment: The same error again... Have you tryed compiling the game from the package link I gave you?

Comment: Nope... But I am able to install all the dependencies.

Comment: Please do this `sudo dpkg -S libtiff4`

Comment: sudo dpkg -S libtiff4libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4/changelog.Debian.gz
libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4/copyright
libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4/TODO
libtiff4: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4
libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4/README
libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4
libtiff4: /usr/share/doc/libtiff4/README.Debian

Comment: Okay. Now do `sudo apt-get remove libtiff4` and then execute the command in the answer

Comment: Now I have compiled the game, it works :D But everything else is messed up. Can't open any folders, or programs. No application is registered as handling this file. And the dropdown menu in the top left corner has only a few programs. Icons are gone too...

Comment: Did `sudo apt-get remove libtiff4` remove any package called `gnome`?

Comment: Removing gnome-applets Removing gnome-panel Removing gnome-about Removing gnome-accessibility-themes Removing gnome-user-share Removing gnome-bluetooth Removing gnome-control-center Removing gnome-disk-utility Removing quadrapassel Removing gnomine ... and lots of these...

Comment: Is there any way just to revert all the changes I've made?

Comment: You can install all of them back by installing gnome, I believe... Please do `sudo apt-get install gnome`

Comment: Never mind, I've reinstalled the whole Ubuntu...